# Ошибка от геокодера Яндекса

Tags: python, yandex-maps-api

Написал вот такой скрипт:

```
import pandas as pd
from yandex_geocoder import Client
import time

data_pod = pd.DataFrame({'Адрес': data['Адрес назначения']})

out_file = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Широта', 'Долгота'])

for counter, i in enumerate(data_pod.index):
    address = data_pod['Адрес'].iloc[i]
    print(counter)
    if address != '-':
        location = Client.coordinates(address)
        lat = location[0]
        long = location[1]
    else:
        lat = 'Not Found'
        long = 'Not Found'

    out_file.loc[i] = [lat, long]
    time.sleep(2)
    if counter%10 == 0:

        print('{} addresses ready.'.format(counter))
```

Как видите, даже добавил паузы, чтобы сервак не заблокировал соединение от слишком частых обращений. Тем не менее, после 50 адресов геокодер отваливается с ошибкой:

```
YandexGeocoderHttpException: Non-200 response from yandex geocoder
```

И непонятно, что с этим делать, ведь на сайте Яндекса написано, что лимит - 25000 запросов в сутки. Гугление подобной проблемы решения не дало (т.к. просто-напросто никто, видимо, не сталкивался с этим). 
Возможно, здесь мне кто-то поможет.

Comment: А ключ вы передаёте? Если нет, то в этом и ошибка - без ключа API не работает уже почти год.

Comment: О каком ключе идёт речь?

Comment: API-ключ, который надо передавать для доступа ко всем карточным API: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/concepts/input_params-docpage/

Comment: Отлично, у меня такой есть. А как вообще понять, куда надо его вводить? У яндекса документация только для JS

Comment: @nutcracker в [документации HTTP-геокодера](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/concepts/input_params-docpage/) описан параметр `apikey`.

Comment: @flapenguin, ну так у меня скрипт питоновский и в библиотеке на питоне некуда указывать этот параметр.

Comment: @nutcracker Судя по [исходному коду](https://github.com/sivakov512/yandex-geocoder/blob/master/yandex_geocoder/client.py#L11) передать `api_key` в `Client` действительно нельзя. Самым простым решением наверное будет использовать другую библиотеку, например, [geopy](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#yandex).

Comment: @Andrey, очень жаль, потому как мне нужно обработать 5000 адресов и желательно получить для них координаты, в `geopy` были аналогичные проблемы, когда скрипт ломался на 10 индексе или раньше, причем проверка самого адреса отдельно никаких проблем не выявила.

Comment: @nutcracker а какой текст ошибки выдавал geopy при падении, не помните? Вы также можете поместить код отвечающий за запросы в `try: except`, чтобы весь скрипт не падал при ошибках. По мере обработки попробуйте сохранять уже обработанные адреса. В итоге, за несколько подходов, обработаете свои 5к адресов. Наверное, еще можно попробовать создать свой класс, наследуясь от `Client` и добавить туда возможность использования ключей. Или вообще просто делать запросы c помощью `requests` и парсить ответ.

Comment: @nutcracker вы используете сторонний модуль для питона, который Яндекс не поддерживает. Обратитесь к его разработчику. Без `apikey` у вас ничего не получится, вы постоянно будете получать `429 Too Many Requests`.

Comment: @flapenguin я догадывался об этом, уж больно скудна сама библиотека, если смотреть исходники на `github`... Ну, постараюсь найти человека, знающего JS.

Comment: @nutcracker зачем вам человек знающий JS? Вот [документация HTTP-геокодера](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/concepts/input_params-docpage/). Там описано как делать HTTP-запросы к геокодеру. HTTP апи - lanuage-agnostic, ему абсолютно все равно из какого языка его используют. В питоне можно воспользоваться [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) (что собственно в библиотеке и делается).